# need to hide button after clicking in window.print

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

i need to display:none to my print button after clicking it.  But that printing page open with window.open command.  so i tried to inline css to not displaying it for printing but it not working.

this is where i put inline css

```
  <input type="button" style="  @media print{ display: none; }"  id="printPageButton"   
 onclick="   window.print();   "    class="printPageButton noprint" value="Print" >
```

Comment: a media query cannot exist in inline css. Put the print style inside of a css file or style tag in the page head.

Comment: " But that printing page open with window.open command" - what does that mean? The code you've shared does not contain any call to `window.open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media query doesn't exists in Inline CSS. You can use CSS **@media** queries in **external CSS file**. For instance:

```css
@media print {
  #printPageButton {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Content to print</h1>
<button id="printPageButton" onClick="window.print();">Print</button>
```

The styles defined within the **@media** print block will only be applied when printing the page. You can test it by clicking the print button in the snippet; you'll get a  page with "Content to print" text.